# Computer changes apostrophes automatically

Tags: windows-xp

When typing in Windows, the computer automatically changes 's (apostrophe s) to s' (s apostrophe) at the end of a word.

How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: in every application or only certain ones?

Comment: Spell checkers will automatically do this.  s' is grammatically correct for possessives that already end in s.  Is this what you're experiencing?

Comment: Is this Microsoft Word, or Notedpad, or your Web Browser? "Typing in Windows" is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're typing in Microsoft Word and experiencing the joy of AutoCorrect.  Here are [instructions from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/turn-on-or-off-autocorrect-options-HP005189430.aspx) to disable the feature.